# Ember.js Component Moving DOM elements

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember.js component called `table-viewer`. It has a toolbar which is a `div` with buttons. I have another ember component called `report-viewer`. It contains a variety of things including a `table-viewer`.

I want to have `report-viewer` add some buttons to the toolbar. What I have works but breaks the Ember connection with the element so I can't change the button text after moving it. Is there a better way to do this?

I have a lot more components than I just said, so defining the complete toolbar in `table-viewer` and setting flags for what to show would be annoying to manage.

Below is what I currently have in `table-viewer` so that any component can add additional buttons to the toolbar:

```
Ember.$('#toolbar').append(Ember.$('#additionalToolbar').html());
Ember.$('#additionalToolbar').remove();
```

Comment: You should be relying on bindings to show/hide things, you rarely need to interact with the DOM directly when you're using ember, can you share your template?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! The following works without breaking Ember connections:

```
Ember.$('#additionalToolbar > button').appendTo(Ember.$('#toolbar'));
```

Comment: As @Kitler pointed out, it is rarely a good idea to use jquery to manipulated the dom when using ember.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what the best approach is without seeing the relevant code. That said, my first suggestion would be a simple yield:

**report-viewer/template.hbs**

```
{{#table-viewer}}
  <button>
    Some button from the report viewer...
  </button>
{{/table-viewer}}
```

**table-viewer/template.hbs**

```
<nav>
  <button>
    Button one
  </button>
  <button>
    Button two
  </button>
  {{yield}}
</nav>
<table>
  ...
</table>
```

If you need more that one yield, you can achieve multiple named yields [with this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30282378/916734).

I'd also suggest splitting the toolbar out into its own component if you haven't already. It feels wrong to put a toolbar button as the block contents of the table-viewer component as I've done above.