# Assertion failed helper when I use custom yields in my application

Tags: ember.js

I'm using Ember v2.5.1.

I'm tryng this solution for my necessity to use two custom yields in same component:

[How can I yield multiple pieces of content into an ember.js component template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282377/how-can-i-yield-multiple-pieces-of-content-into-an-ember-js-component-template)

This is my code:

```
// component 
{{#father-component as |f|}}
  {{#f.left-content}} 
    This is a content
  {{/f.left-content}}
  {{#f.right-content}}
    This is a another content
  {{/f.right-content}}
{{/father-component}}

// father-component
<div class="left">
  {{yield (hash left-content = (component "foo-content"))}}
</div>
<div class="right">
  {{yield (hash right-content = (component "foo-content"))}}
</div>

// foo-content 
{{yield}}
```

In https://ember-twiddle.com/ this [works nicelly](https://ember-twiddle.com/58246c346ae25dd5548018cb32134604?openFiles=templates.components.father-component.hbs%2C), but in my localhost this dosn't works and return this error

> Assertion Failed: A helper named 'f.right-content' could not be found

Some help?

I work with app exporting the components, and the path js and hbs separetly.

---

### Edit

When I add {{log f}} in parent component this happens.

[image]

Comment: I'd double check your templates to make sure there's no typo. The fact that this works in the twiddle is an indication that it's probably a simple error. Maybe copy paste the twiddle templates / component files into your local project just to be safe.

Comment: Try `f.rightContent` and `f.leftContent`?

Comment: Well.. I'm using ember +v2.5, I tried the two comments but still happened the same error =( `Assertion Failed: A helper named 'f.rightContent' could not be found`

Comment: @MarceloBoni try logging `f` in the parent component template block: `{{log "f is: " f}}`

Comment: I go add a snapshot in the question.

Comment: Maybe a limitation of the version I'm using? I'm creating an application in this version to test....

Comment: @MarceloBoni the twiddle version uses Ember v3.4.3. What version are you using? Seems like only one of the `yields` is coming through.

Comment: The twiddle version works in v2.12 to, my case is v2.5.1. I was not able to recreate the environment.

Comment: Have a similar discuss in github of ember.  https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/17240

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in ember repo discussing the trick you are using for multiple yields. Robert Jackson (@rwjblue), who is a member of the ember's core team, said in [a comment](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/17240#issuecomment-445107748) that this technique only worked due to a bug that has been fixed in Ember 3.6. I haven't double checked but I would guess that the bug was added after 2.5.1, which you are using. The Ember Twiddle seems to support only versions in which this bug was alive.

TL;DR: If you want to use that approach you need to upgrade to a version that has this bug included. But I would strongly advise not to do so cause it's not supported and won't work with Ember 3.6+.

It's to sad that [Yieldable named blocks RFC](https://emberjs.github.io/rfcs/0460-yieldable-named-blocks.html) isn't implemented yet. You could track the status in the [related tracking issue](https://github.com/emberjs/rfc-tracking/issues/44). As far as I know there is also no polyfill available (yet).

Comment: Any idea how I can implement anything like this without having to take advantage of this "hack"?

Comment: I think it should be fine if you yield a no-op component instead of `undefined`. But haven't tested.